# Can't open Orca settings on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, settings, accessibility, orca

I use Ubuntu 13.04. I found out Orca could be enabled in Universal Access, but I cannot find its GUI based settings manager.

I can't even start its settings manager via the command `orca --setup` or with the key combination <kbd>Insert</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

It's very convenient/needed for a blind user to change the general settings like speaking rate, pitch and many other things. It's a lot less accessible if one has to run `orca --text-setup` every time or edit a configuration file.

How can I open the Orca settings manager?

Comment: do you have gnome? what version of orca do you have? $orca -v  do you have the dependencies? https://github.com/GNOME/orca   also, revisit this page:https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Orca/DownloadInstall

Comment: @Tennom - 13.04 was supported not for a long time ... and contact simply the maintainer of Orca (in Menue of Orca is an info-entry). Or you find out the maintainer by package-query ?

Answer (score 1):

The orca setup is now working in 16.04 (LTS)

Please upgrade to the latest version of Ubuntu.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/573478)

Comment: Yes it does answer it. This question must be closed down to stop the unanswered page being clogged with bug reports from 2013. Please reconsider deleting every answer to this post if you don't have a better answer to provide.

Comment: @MartinOwens-doctormo-, Could you include the bug link if you have it?

Comment: @AndroidDev, It may not be the best solution to the OP. But it is still an option to solve the problem. (Even partial solutions are accepted in Ask Ubuntu, if this was so)